# TensorFlow could not create a descriptor for a pooling forward propagation primitive

Tags: python, tensorflow, pooling

I have a simple CNN model which uses an `AveragePooling2D` layer.

When I try to train the model with `model.fit` I get the following error:

```
AbortedError:  Operation received an exception:Status: 2, message: could not create a descriptor for a pooling forward propagation primitive, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_avgpooling_op.cc: 165

[[node simplecnn/average_pooling2d_6/AvgPool (defined at <ipython-input-221-8ef5297e7704>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_97706]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I'm using tensorflow version 2.2.0 and mkl version 2020.2.

What is causing this?

I prefer to find the cause and not say just change versions of tensorflow.